# How can I install xclip on an EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, github, amazon-ec2, yum

I'm following [Github's instructions for adding an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux). I've generated the id_rsa.pub file from my AWS EC2 instance, but I cannot complete the step that has me copy the contents of the file using xclip because I cannot install xclip onto the EC2 instance.

1. I tried to install xclip on the EC2 instance using `sudo yum install
   xclip`, but that didn't work ("No package xclip available").
2. So I looked around and found [more detailed install instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/), but they
   didn't work either ("curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"), and the suggested correct URLs in the comments also failed.
3. (I also tried just copying the text contents of the id_rsa.pub file using Putty and ctl-c, but Github declared the resulting key invalid.)

So, how do I install xclip on 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I needed this today for a file larger than a ssh-key, and cat was not enough. You need to enable the EPEL repo in EC2 in order to get xclip:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install xclip -y
```

Comment: tried the accepted solution and not working in amazon linux 2

Answer (score 13):

You don't need xclip. Just `ssh` into the EC2 instance and `cat` the key to your terminal, then copy and paste it from your terminal to wherever you need it.

Comment: Using `cat` worked. Now just need github to document their SSH steps.

Comment: Not an answer to the question

Comment: you can't use `cat` all the time the cases actually. what if you want to copy a large file?

Comment: @Yar obviously, but the initial question was about a ssh key, which is small. If you need to transfer larger files, scp is the way, or if that's not possible, maybe zmodem.

Comment: I agree, not an answer to the question. I need to copy a different, large buffer to the clipboard

Comment: Using `xclip` is convenient even over `ssh`. Here's an example - https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-copy-a-selection-from-tmux-to-the-systems-clipboard . And it works perfectly if you `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install xclip -y
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/kevin-kientopp/7a1dee73ab0f1bdb21fe158407a028ea

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to wake up the zombies but in case someone is still wondering you can `wget` the rpm (i.e. from [here](https://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15289734/dir/redhat_el_6/com/xclip-0.12-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)) and then

```
sudo yum localinstall xclip-0.12-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

**Note:** you may need to do the same for some dependencies.