# Unable to run Pyperclip on AWS cloud9

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

When I try to run Pyperclip on AWS cloud9, I get the following error
I get the following error

```
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 1024))
display.start()

pyperclip.copy("HELLO!! WORLD!!")
print(pyperclip.paste())

display.stop()
```

> Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.

I've also installed xclip, see below.
[How can I install xclip on an EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146314/how-can-i-install-xclip-on-an-ec2-instance)

```
>pip list
pyperclip 1.8.1

>yum list installed
xclip.x86_64 0.12-1.el6 @epel
```

GUI environment is also available in Xvfb.
Please let me know how I can run Pyperclip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `pyperclip` module after creating the display, as this module checks for it during initialization.

Like this:

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=False, size=(1280, 1024))
display.start()

import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy("HELLO!! WORLD!!")
print(pyperclip.paste())

display.stop()
```